# How to make image button

Tags: c#, winforms

I was wondering how could I do this. I know I can use the button component but it has the little gray stuff around it when I give it a image. With image button how could I show another image for the hover effect

Comment: Are you talking about WinForms, WPF or ASP.NET?

Comment: I'm not that skilled in WinForms, but I think you can turn of border and background on ImageButtons, and then, there is probably some event for mouseover or something like that you can use to change the image.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You want to create a button with no border but displays different images when the user hovers over it with the mouse?  Here's how you can do it:

1. Add an `ImageList` control to your form at add two images, one for the button's normal appearance and one for when the mouse is hovering over.
2. Add your button and set the following properties:
   `FlatStyle` = Flat
   `FlatAppearance.BorderColor` (and maybe `MouseOverBackColor` & `MouseDownBackColor`) to your form's background color
   `ImageList` = the ImageList you added to the form
   `ImageIndex` to the index value of your normal image

Code the MouseHover and MouseLeave events for the button like this:

```
// ImageList index value for the hover image.
private void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e) => button1.ImageIndex = 1;

// ImageList index value for the normal image.
private void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e) => button1.ImageIndex = 0;
```

I believe that will give you the visual effect you're looking for.

Comment: Absolutely perfect

Answer (score 4):

**Small summary** (Border, MouseDownBackColor, MouseOverBackColor)

**FlatApperance**

`BorderColor` = Black or what ever you want
`BorderSize` = can be set to 0
`MouseDownBackColor` = Transparent
`MouseOverBackColor` = Transparent

`Text` = none

**For MouseDown**:

```
// ImageList index value for the mouse down image.
private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) => button1.ImageIndex = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the BackgroundImage property for the button. You can also use the OnMouseEnter and OnMouseExit events to change the background as per your request.

See [BackgroundImage](http://BackgorundImage) [OnMouseEnter](http://OnMouseEnter) [OnMouseLeave](http://OnMouseLeave)

Answer (score -1):

I also needed an image button, but I wanted one like the ToolstripMenuButton.
With the correct borders and colors on hover.
So I made a custom control to do just that:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace LastenBoekInfrastructure.Controls.Controls
{
    [DefaultEvent("Click")]
    public class ImageButton : UserControl
    {
        public string ToolTipText
        {
            get { return _bButton.ToolTipText; }
            set { _bButton.ToolTipText = value; }
        }

        public bool CheckOnClick
        {
            get { return _bButton.CheckOnClick; }
            set { _bButton.CheckOnClick = value; }
        }

        public bool DoubleClickEnabled
        {
            get { return _bButton.DoubleClickEnabled; }
            set { _bButton.DoubleClickEnabled = value; }
        }

        public System.Drawing.Image Image
        {
            get { return _bButton.Image; }
            set { _bButton.Image = value; }
        }

        public new event EventHandler Click;
        public new event EventHandler DoubleClick;

        private ToolStrip _tsMain;
        private ToolStripButton _bButton;

        public ImageButton()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            var resources = new ComponentResourceManager(typeof(ImageButton));
            _tsMain = new ToolStrip();
            _bButton = new ToolStripButton();
            _tsMain.SuspendLayout();
            SuspendLayout();

            // 
            // tsMain
            // 
            _tsMain.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            _tsMain.CanOverflow = false;
            _tsMain.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            _tsMain.GripMargin = new Padding(0);
            _tsMain.GripStyle = ToolStripGripStyle.Hidden;
            _tsMain.Items.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] {
            _bButton});
            _tsMain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            _tsMain.Name = "_tsMain";
            _tsMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);
            _tsMain.TabIndex = 0;
            _tsMain.Renderer = new ImageButtonToolStripSystemRenderer();
            // 
            // bButton
            // 
            _bButton.DisplayStyle = ToolStripItemDisplayStyle.Image;
            _bButton.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("_bButton.Image")));
            _bButton.ImageTransparentColor = System.Drawing.Color.Magenta;
            _bButton.Name = "_bButton";
            _bButton.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(23, 22);
            _bButton.Click += bButton_Click;
            _bButton.DoubleClick += bButton_DoubleClick;
            // 
            // ImageButton
            // 
            Controls.Add(_tsMain);
            Name = "ImageButton";
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(25, 25);
            _tsMain.ResumeLayout(false);
            _tsMain.PerformLayout();
            ResumeLayout(false);
            PerformLayout();
        }

        void bButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Click != null)
            {
                Click(this, e);
            }
        }

        void bButton_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(DoubleClick != null)
            {
                DoubleClick(this, e);
            }
        }

        public class ImageButtonToolStripSystemRenderer : ToolStripSystemRenderer
        {
            protected override void OnRenderToolStripBorder(ToolStripRenderEventArgs e)
            {
                //base.OnRenderToolStripBorder(e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```