# Clearing textboxes c#

Tags: c#

So I have:

3 text-boxes, 1 Clear all button (which should clear ALL text-boxes), and 1 clear selected text-box (which clears only the selected text-box).

How would I go about doing this? Here is my code:

```
        private void ClearAllTextBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control c in Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                c.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

I have not posted code for the "Clear Current Field" button.

With this, the first time I press the button it only clears the SecondOperatorTextBox and the ResultTextBox. If I click it one more time it then clears the FirstOperatorTextBox.

How would I clear all 3 text-boxes with 1 button, and only clear selected with another button?

Comment: The code you posted will clear all three each time the button is clicked. I suspect you've gotten something wrong when connecting the event to the button. What does the debugger tell you if you set a breakpoint on `FirstOperandTextBox.Clear();` and then click the clear all button? Also, by *selected*, do you mean *focused*?

Comment: @Ken White By "selected" I mean the textbox where the cursor is placed.

Comment: Then you mean *focused*. It's the textbox that is the focused control.

Comment: `and only clear selected with another button` Keep in mind once you click this button, your TextBox will lose *focus*. There's a nice little roundabout, albeit hacky way, [that you can find here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937459/get-the-currently-focused-textbox-in-c-sharp).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915188/clearing-two-textbox-text-either-one-which-is-selected?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Your `ClearAllTextBoxes_Click` event handler seems to clear all the three Textboxes, so I will try to answer the clear "selected textbox" with one button.

The problem I see here is what do you mean by selected text box? It may mean focused TextBox (which also allows editing if enabled and not readonly), but the focus is lost when you go to another control (i.e. when pushing a button).

I think the most user friendly approach is to have a clear button next to each textbox and pushing it will clear that particular textbox. In order to keep your UI as clean as possible, the button should not contain text, but an image. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395216/how-to-make-image-button) for more details about doing this.

Also, since you have three textboxes and possibly this number may grow in the future, you may consider creating a custom control, something like a "`ClearableTextBox`". This control can simply have a TextBox and a button with an image capable of clearing the TextBox. More information about how to create such a custom control (actually a composite one since you just put standard controls together) can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6h7e207(v=vs.100).aspx).

Comment: It clears all 3 but, I have to click it 3 times for it to do so. Also, this is for a homework assignment and this is how the professor wants us to clear it.

Comment: @Paulie - code you showed cannot produce effect you are describing

Comment: @Igor I know, I made some changes and it still isn't working

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way:

1. Place a private variable in your form to remember the last TextBox
   that was selected (a.k.a. focused).
2. Wire up all the text boxes that you want to be able to execute "clear selected" on to the "Enter" event.
3. When the enter event occurs, set the value of the private variable to the sender that fired the event.
4. When you click "Clear Selected", just call the .Clear() method on the item that was last selected.

And now some code:

```
public partial class MyForm : Form
{
    private TextBox _lastSelected = null;

    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.Enter += textBox_Enter;
        textBox2.Enter += textBox_Enter;
        textBox3.Enter += textBox_Enter;
    }

    private void buttonClearAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();
        textBox3.Clear();
    }

    private void buttonClearSelected_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_lastSelected == null) return;

        _lastSelected.Clear();
    }

    private void textBox_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _lastSelected = (TextBox)sender;
    }
}
```

Comment: For the ClearAll you listed, that's what I put the first time and it didn't work. I had to click the ClearAllButton 3 times because it only cleared one at a time.

Comment: It did for the "Clear focused button", not for the "Clear All"

Comment: @Paulie - as an alternative to the "Clear All" that you posted in your question, I would suggest starting with simply listing all of the textboxes items that you want cleared one by one. When I coded up my answer it worked just fine for me. Could it be possible that other code is affecting the behavior of your Clear All method? As the saying goes, "make it work, make it right, make it fast".

Comment: It actually was other code that was interfering. I got it to work using the code I listed above, I had to do some cleaning. I appreciate your help.